# Javascript performance when making chess board

Tags: javascript, performance

I use html table to draw a chess board(8x8), then generate a yellow cell appear randomly in chess board. This is the code:

```
$('#random').click(function(){
                for (i=0; i<100; i++){
                    setInterval(function(){
                        resetBoard(); // re-draw chess board without yellow cell
                        var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 64));
                        $('.chess-board tr td').eq(index).css('background-color', 'yellow');    
            }, 150);
                }
});
```

The appearence of yellow cell doesn't stop. And that code make browser compute very much (I saw in Task Manager Firefox use 32% CPU while run this).
What is the problem in this, thank bro ?

Comment: you are using `setInterval` in `for` loop, causing so much `setInterval functions` running in parallel, you should clear previous `setInterval` before registering new one

Comment: You are probably want to use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: Please have a courtesy to accept someone's answer which was close or helped to solve the issue. BTW someone has downvoted your question idk why so upvoted to balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep initializing a sequence of new ***repetitive timers*** in a for loop so those timer functions are ultimately triggered in a row with very small delay between each of them (no, please). Thus, your event loop should be massively busy like this:

> **Time lapse**
>
> ---
>
> T0 ........... **interval#1** first runs
>
> T0+1 ......... **interval#2** first runs
>
> T0+3 ......... **interval#3** first runs
>
> ...
>
> T0+15 ........ **interval#16** first runs
>
> .............. **interval#1** reruns
>
> T0+16 ........ **interval#17** first runs
>
> .............. **interval#2** reruns
>
> .... (lots of intervals start to concur, keep CPU busy)

**If you insist to use timer to delay the render of your board.** Keep repeating your timer even though the new timers are being added in does not make much sense. I'm not sure why you need this. This is multiplying your tasks and makes your app far from responsiveness.

*You should better use timeout to trigger your function in your scenario*

You may want to run the next timer once the previous timer finishes instead of sequentially run a bulk load of timers continuously. The skeleton of the code may look like this:

```
var n=0;
function renderBoard(){
    resetBoard(); // re-draw chess board without yellow cell
    var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 64));
    $('.chess-board tr td').eq(index).css('background-color', 'yellow');

    // After finish, add a delay of 150 ms to run the subsequent action
    n++;
    if (n<100)
       setTimeout(renderBoard, 150);
}

setTimeout(renderBoard, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created 100 interval that run every 150 milliseconds! that is 666 times (oh the irony) every second... In each one you reset the board, and search the DOM for

```
$('.chess-board tr td')
```

which should be cached (saved to a variable) before any interval is called.

What are you trying to do do with these intervals?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#random').click(function(){
    var $chessCell = $('.chess-board tr td');
    for (i=0; i<100; i++){  // probably should not use this loop
      update();
    }
});
function update() {
        resetBoard(); // re-draw chess board without yellow cell
        var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 64));
        $chessCell.eq(index).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        setTimer(); 
}

function setTimer() {
  timeout = setTimeout(update, 150);
}
```

Comment: And this does what...fixes what...how?

Comment: it makes sure that your previous `update` was complete before running next `update`